# Does AppEngine data transfered to google-owned domain count as "Outgoing Network Traffic"?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I write an app engine app that, say, transfers data between Google Drive and YouTube, is that considered "outgoing network traffic"?  Amazon does not charge data transfer fees for data transferred intra-zone, for example.  Google doesn't really expose a notion of zones or any other similar concept (that I know of) so that this can be figured out.

I know I can write an app to test it, but that's considerably more work.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are also looking at [Requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests) in [AppEngine Quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas).  The most reasonable interpretation is that data transfers to Google Drive and YouTube are also counted as outgoing network traffic.  If they were not, the document would have to specifically mention an exception, but it does not.